# How to replace Json array in json object and put another based on matching id using javascrypt. my project is react typescrypt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, typescript

I have JSON as such

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "traps": [
            {
                "size": "big",
                "for": "none",
                "amount": 8
            },
            {
                "size": "large",
                "for": "spa",
                "amount": 4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "traps": {
            "traps": {
                "children": [
                    {
                        "trap": {
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "size": {
                                        "content": "regular"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "for": {
                                        "content": "none"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "amount": {
                                        "content": "10"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "trap": {
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "size": {
                                        "content": "regular"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "for": {
                                        "content": "spa"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "for": {
                                        "content": "2"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

and I want to replace it's traps elements with those who match on this list

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "trap": [
                {
                    "size": "regular",
                    "for": "Si",
                    "amount": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "trap": [
                {
                    "size": "ad",
                    "for": "dad",
                    "amount": "0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "trap": [
                {
                    "size": "ran",
                    "for": "sultan",
                    "amount": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
]
```

meaning that I want to discard traps from the first document and put traps from second one. The solution I need is element with id = 0 to abandon it's traps value and use the one witch is with id=0 from the second Json. ALSO the element with ID:1 in the first document needs to discard his traps elements and replace them with the other two that has id:1 in the second document.

Thank you very much.

I tried to update the first with the values of second but each element in the first document takes the whole 3 traps from the second or none at all

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first block of JSON is called `start` and that the second block of JSON is called `update` then the following code will do the trick, from my reading of the question:

```js
const trapById = update.flat(1).reduce((acc, val) => {
  const { id, trap } = val;
  if (!acc[id]) {
    return { ...acc, [id]: trap };
  } else {
    return { ...acc, [id]: [...acc[id], ...trap] };
  }
}, {});

const newData = start.map(({ id }) => ({ id, trap: trapById[id] }));
```

The call to reduce makes an object where the key is the id, and the value is the new value for the `trap` array. The map call then creates a new array from the starting data, replacing the old trap field with the new one. Hope this helps.